# Python - unable to parse nested JSON

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I have the following JSON that contains JSON fields(in the `value` keys):

```
PAYLOAD_JSON = '''
 {
     "type":"block_actions",
     "team":{
        "id":"ABCDEF",
        "domain":"XXXX"
     },
     "user":{
        "id":"U012A3CDE",
        "username":"spengler",
        "name":"spengler",
        "team_id":"T9XJ4RGNQ"
     },
     "api_app_id":"AMU4M2QL8",
     "token":"GBGG7mn61zg0a62MT9blXJnn",
     "container":{
        "type":"message",
        "message_ts":"1567945126.000100",
        "channel_id":"DMGSNFCSX",
        "is_ephemeral":false
     },
     "trigger_id":"754598374743.337616866772.8c4b2dc28ca7fd4c8941247c1a01c7dd",
     "channel":{
        "id":"DMGSNFCSX",
        "name":"directmessage"
     },
     "message":{
        "type":"message",
        "subtype":"bot_message",
        "text":"This content can't be displayed.",
        "ts":"1567945126.000100",
        "username":"BlockTest",
        "bot_id":"BMWFS6KSA",
        "blocks":[
           {
              "type":"section",
              "block_id":"F9iYK",
              "text":{
                 "type":"mrkdwn",
                 "text":"Hopa this is a test. ",
                 "verbatim":false
              },
              "accessory":{
                 "type":"button",
                 "text":{
                    "type":"plain_text",
                    "text":"Eyy",
                    "emoji":true
                 },
                 "value":"{\"name\": \"abcdef\", \"reply\": \"Thanks\"}",
                 "action_id":"W9J"
              }
           }
        ]
     },
     "response_url":"hooks.slack.com",
     "actions":[
        {
           "action_id":"W9J",
           "block_id":"F9iYK",
           "text":{
              "type":"plain_text",
              "text":"Eyy",
              "emoji":true
           },
           "value":"{\"name\": \"abcdef\", \"reply\": \"Thanks\"}",
           "type":"button",
           "action_ts":"1567949681.728426"
        }
     ]
  }
'''
```

When I try to use `json.loads()`, I get the error: `json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting ',' delimiter: line 50 column 29 (char 1358)`. 
I have tried to use a hook in the `loads` function but to no avail:

```
def hook(obj):
    value = obj.get('value')
    if value and isinstance(value, str):
        obj['value'] = json.loads(value, object_hook=hook)
    return obj
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that these occurrences: `"value":"{\"name\": \"abcdef\", \"reply\": \"Thanks\"}",` break the json parsing.

Quick dirty fix:

```py
PAYLOAD_JSON = PAYLOAD_JSON.replace('\\"', '').replace('"{', '{').replace('}"', '}')
```

And now you could do:

```
>>> js=json.loads(PAYLOAD_JSON)
>>> print(js["message"]["blocks"][0]["accessory"]["value"])
{'name': 'abcdef', 'reply': 'Thanks'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace both occurences of
`"value":"{\"name\": \"abcdef\", \"reply\": \"Thanks\"}",`
with
    `"value":{"name": "abcdef", "reply": "Thanks\"}",`
and it'll work.

Comment: You mean before I parse it? how would I do it in the code?

Comment: Are you initializing this Payload in your code or are you getting it from a request variable?
And yes, it'll be done before you do json.loads

Comment: I'm getting it from a POST request.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is a little out of context - because I used the above string for testing. Addind `r` to the beginning of the string solved it.